what does this mean? I'm new to computers and I recently started having this issue where my computer shuts off when I play certain games

I looked it up and someone told me to run this ram test. I'm currently running it and I've gotten 2 error as shown in the picture

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

looks like a memory failure ... same address, same bit, "stuck" at 1 - replace RAM would be a suggestion

There's no picture, so this is a guess.
Whenever a computer shuts down in the middle of doing something intense, I assume first that it's overheating.

The most common cause of PC shutting off is either, your processor or GPU is not being able to take the load of your certain games (resulting in overheating, slow down or shutting off).
Take a temperature test on GPU (ideally be under 80C) but is this test taken soon after you played?
If temperature is the cause, go for fan's cleaning and ensure adequate air inflow in the PC case.
There could be other reasons too, please verify if you have any of them.
